# Is RETURN going out the method at any moment, even if it is in a complex IF statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, return

I have a code like this:

```
private final Something (SomethingElse nimportant)

    List list = (List) mListOfSomething.get(SOME_ENUMS);

    if (list == null) 
// dont ask me why not list.isEmpty(), I'm not the author of this code)
        list = new ArrayList();

        if (transaction.getPartner() instanceof IAnotherSomething) {

            IAnotherSomething ias = (IAnotherSomething) transaction.getPartner();
            return ias.getContract().next();
        }

// NIMPORTANT code ommited, produces boolean "something"

        if (something) {
            // something happens
            list.add(contract)
        }

        if (!something) {
            // something else happens
            list.add(contract)
        }
    }

    return (IContract) list.get(0);
}
```

I have a brainpain - IF the list IS empty, (or == null) AND this if statement `(transaction.getPartner() instanceof IAnotherSomething)` is true, the method shoud exit on this if statement and should return `ias.getContract().next()` - or am I wrong about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A return statements ends the execution of the method, returning the specified value to the caller of the method, no matter where it is placed within the method. It doesn't matter if it's inside a "complex if statement".

The are a few special cases in which a return statement won't be the last statement executed in the method :

1. The return statement is wrapped in a try clause containing a finally block, which will be executed before returning from the method.
2. The return statement is wrapped in a try clause and the evaluation of the expression to be returned throws an exception that is caught by a catch block, which will be executed (and must have a return statement or throw an exception).

Comment: Correct. Minor detail about "ends the execution of the method": `finally` blocks are still being run before it goes back to the caller.

Comment: Thanks, I have asked this question cause a far more experienced coworker mixed up my mind saying that it will continue to the next if statements... So I was right right at the first time, but the power of authority, you know... :) Still, thanks for this answer!

Comment: @Thilo Yep, I just thought about that after posting the answer, and just finished editing the answer.